# Whitenoise to serve static files locally

Tags: python, django, whitenoise

As described in their docs [here](http://whitenoise.evans.io/en/stable/django.html), I am configured my application to serve static files **locally**.

The only problem I am facing is that I am unable to determine if it is django or whitenoise which is serving static files?

Steps which I followed:

```
pip install whitenoise # install whitenoise
pip install brotlipy # install brotlipy for compression

INSTALLED_APPS = [

# default django apps
'django.contrib.messages',

# REMOVE IN PRODUCTION
# See: http://whitenoise.evans.io/en/stable/django.html#using-whitenoise-in-development
'whitenoise.runserver_nostatic',

'django.contrib.staticfiles',
# other apps
]


# add white-noise middleware

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',

    # static files serving
    'whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware',


    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
     # other middlewares
]


# add staticfiles 
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'whitenoise.storage.CompressedManifestStaticFilesStorage'

# run collecstatic
python manage.py collectstatic

# restart the server
python manage.py runserver

# This gives me following

[10/Apr/2018 12:12:40] "GET /static/debug_toolbar/css/print.css HTTP/1.1" 304 0
[10/Apr/2018 12:12:40] "GET /static/chartkick.js HTTP/1.1" 304 0
[10/Apr/2018 12:12:40] "GET /static/debug_toolbar/js/jquery_pre.js HTTP/1.1" 304 0

However, I expect something like this,

[10/Apr/2018 12:12:40] "GET /static/debug_toolbar/css/print.636363s6s.css HTTP/1.1" 304 0
[10/Apr/2018 12:12:40] "GET /static/chartkick.2623678s3cdce3.js HTTP/1.1" 304 0
[10/Apr/2018 12:12:40] "GET /static/debug_toolbar/js/jquery_pre.6276gdg3js8j.js HTTP/1.1" 304 0
```

How can I check if whitenoise is working and that it is serving static files?

Answer (score 1):

Since it's been quite a while since you asked this question, I imagine you've found an answer by now. But if anyone else stumbles on it, I've found that Django won't serve static files if you have `DEBUG=False`. So if you have that setting and you're still seeing static, it's likely being done by whitenoise.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question, but I'm answering here for posterity. When running
`python manage.py runserver`, the runserver takes over management of static files. However, you can run `python manage.py runserver --nostatic` or add "whitenoise.runserver_nostatic" as the first in the INSTALLED_APPS in your setting.py, see [here](https://whitenoise.readthedocs.io/en/stable/django.html#using-whitenoise-in-development)